# Angular routing otherwise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, ngroute

I'am writing an homepage using javascript, an express server and angular.
Currently I have following routing:

```
function config($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/login/login.view.html',
    controller: 'loginCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  })
  .when('/home', {
    templateUrl: '/home/home.view.html',
    controller: 'homeCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  })
  .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}
```

Instead of the redirection in .otherwise to login page I would like that the user gets an page like:

> **Not found**
>
> The requested URL <requestedURL> was not found on this server.

How can I get the requested url in the controller of redirected page?
Or what is the common way to implement this?

Kind regards,
Wolfgang